# What's a word to describe 'thinking unconstrained by time'

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Most of us think existentially, until we start thinking about things in the future, or things in the past...but it's usually from the vantage point of 'now.'  The word or term I'm looking for is abstract thinking from any vantage point in time.

For example, if I want to buy a new car, I'll consider the costs/benefits of the choices available to me at this time.  But when I start thinking about the resale price ten years from now, I'm leaving my current circumstances to venture into my possible future.  And then, when I consider how I came up with my list of costs/benefits by looking into my past and what motivates what I want now, then once again, I'm not "in the moment."

As a counselor, I often see my clients unbound by time (which is, afterall, not what most people think it is), focused more on potential, requirements and processes, and not the timing--I'm looking for a word that can help me teach that kind of thinking, if such a word or term exists.

As a teacher, I offer paths for my students to consider that are not bound by time, and encourage them to avoid getting stuck on the timing, but focus on recognizing opportunities instead.  Once again, that kind of thinking is not temporal, it is "_____."

Comment: Creative, divergent, exploratory.

Comment: Time-independent (though thinking of history, or future possibilities, hardly qualifies).

Comment: I mean, "atemporal" is a word. You could also use "ideal" or "transcendental" but those both have genealogies within multiple religious-philosophical traditions that might require more explanation than it's worth.

Comment: While not strictly about time in particular, ***thinking holistically*** might cover that and other beneficial viewpoints as well.

Comment: I agree with @joseph_morris -- there's no need to create a word when atemporal describes it well.